# Compare values in two windows

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am automating the reports, the data in reports need to compare with UI. The report is loading fine, now I need to open UI in another window. Then read the values in both windows and then compare the values. This is the approach I'm following. Here the problem is after loading the report, I used `driver.get(""); driver.swichto.window();` but I am unable to do any operation in 2nd window.

Is this approach is correct? or any other way is there?

How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

To switch to the last open window do :

```
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, I tried this control focusing to new window but the thing is unable to do any operation..

Comment: @SubbaraoGaddam Do you have an `<iframe>` on the 2nd window ?

Comment: NO.. There are no frames